# Disabling all controls from a parent control

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
Public Sub disableControls(parent As Control, Optional ByVal disable As Boolean = True)
    For Each child As Control In parent.Controls
        ClearControls(child)
    Next
    If disable = True Then
        TryCast(parent, TextBox).Enabled = False
        TryCast(parent, ComboBox).Enabled = False
        TryCast(parent, DateTimePicker).Enabled = False
        TryCast(parent, Button).Enabled = False
    Else
        TryCast(parent, TextBox).Enabled = True
        TryCast(parent, ComboBox).Enabled = True
        TryCast(parent, DateTimePicker).Enabled = True
        TryCast(parent, Button).Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Need help, I'm getting  `NullReferenceException was unhandled` on line  `TryCast(parent, TextBox).Enabled = False`

Comment: i cant edit the ClearControls(child) , even if i changed it to disableControls(child) im still getting that nullreferenceexception

Comment: If the parent control is not a TextBox that line become `Nothing.Enabled = false`. As you can see this will raise the exception

Comment: However if I understand your code you could set the Enabled property directly on the Control passed.